# How to make a reference to public const string from aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to make a reference to public const string from aspx page with c#

In VB its <% = MY_DATA%>

Comment: Should be exactly the same in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# it's exactly the same.

Did you try that, and did you have any problems using it?